# Electric Field calculation

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

What are the limits(lower and upper) of electric field of the differential element in the calculation of electric field of some standard configuration

Eg:[image]
 electric field calculation for spherical shell[image]

a: radius of the shell

r: distance of the point(where field due to the shell is calculated)from the centre of the shell

What are the limits of dE in this case?

Comment: Electric field is an inexact differential.

Comment: Inexact integral means

Comment: inexact integral means that it does not require limits.

Comment: Why doesn't it require limits

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The best would be to think for every such case you get. If you want in this case, for whole sphere, you will get it for theta varying from 0 to $\pi$. Some another important things to keep in mind : if you are dealing with vectors (like electric field) ; the choice of reference (origin) etc